# Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory doesn't create

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

When a try to Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() I receive this error log:

```
mar 14, 2024 4:00:03 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: Pizzeria]
mar 14, 2024 4:00:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
mar 14, 2024 4:00:07 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
mar 14, 2024 4:00:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
mar 14, 2024 4:00:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzeria]
mar 14, 2024 4:00:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****}
mar 14, 2024 4:00:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
mar 14, 2024 4:00:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
mar 14, 2024 4:00:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and this is my persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="Pizzeria">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzeria" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.username" value="root" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="portentoso" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name = "hibernate.format_sq" value = "true" />
            
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I tried to use different hibernate and connector versions, and connector-java insteed of connector-j. It results in different similar errors.

Tried to use javax properties name. No change.

I'm using MySQL80. 8.0.34

Edit: I tried to use code on server (TomCat 9) and error log was different

```
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.6.Final}
mar 14, 2024 6:05:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mar 14, 2024 6:05:15 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
mar 14, 2024 6:05:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
mar 14, 2024 6:05:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
mar 14, 2024 6:05:15 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
mar 14, 2024 6:05:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
```

Comment: Does the 'pizerria' database referenced in the JDBC url actually exist? There is no configuration here to automatically generate anything so you have to manually create a database with tables yourself. And the configured database user needs to be able to access it.

Comment: Triple checked addresses, username and pass.